# Angular Services in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to ReactJS and I'm working on the Front-End side of a project I have developed myself. The project is meant to be a site where users can logIn and post messages.

I have developed my back-end using Spring, Kotlin and MongoDB as DDBB, and have developed the API to perform all the necessary actions.
I have already developed the front-end side in Angular 6, since I know how to do that, and I have the site running correctly.

However, I'm trying to learn ReactJS, and I want to 'replicate' what I've done in Angular with React. After some tutorials and stuff, I have been able to develop my LoginComponent, which can fetch correctly the userInformation from the backend.

Here's then my question: In Angular, I use services to store variables that I may need from different routes, such as the userId (I will query the messages using that). I have not noticed how to do that in React, any idea?

Sorry for the poor explanation, I'm new to React.

Comment: One thing to clarify, React is mainly a library that takes in data and spits out HTML. It does some other stuff too, but it doesn't have as many features out of the box as Angular does. Angular provides many other abstractions like services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a place to store the application state, you can use rxjs or mobx observables, or you can use redux. I personally like observables, as there is a lot of boilerplate in redux.

In react, your smart components will usually import pure functions from services that perform actions on the stores, and derive its rendering from the application state that is passed down to dumb rendering components.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please provide an example? I use rxjs in Angular, but cannot find any with react and don't know how to include it and declare the observable which will be later on subscribed to in order to get the data